# URLConnection encoding issue with accent character

Tags: java, url

I've got an issue with the `URLConnection` encoding trying to send a text.

My code is this:

```
final URL url = new URL(urlString);
final URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

final DataOutputStream urlDataOut = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
urlDataOut.writeBytes(prepareData.toString());
urlDataOut.flush();
urlDataOut.close();
```

My `prepareData.toString()` contains a word with an "è" and as soon as the urlDataOut is written it will contain the diamond with the question mark instead of the "è" letter and the status of the write is FAILURE.

Does anybody know how to face this issue?

Comment: Can you try `urlDataOut.writeUTF(prepareData.toString())`?

Comment: where are you trying to print this?  To a console?  You should read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [`DataOutputStream.writeBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeBytes%28java.lang.String%29) method is not suitable for any character encoding. Its documentation says:

> Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits.

Using the method `writeUTF` will not be feasible either. It writes two bytes containing the length of the encoded `String` (number of bytes) which the server would interpret as characters at the beginning.

So you should use the standard way of writing text to an `OutputStream`:

```
Writer w=new OutputStreamWriter(
                  urlConnection.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
w.write(prepareData.toString());
w.flush();
w.close();
```

Comment: Hi Holger, 

thanks for your reply. I tested the DataOutputStream.writeUTF and it worked, I can't use StandardCharsets.UTF_8 as I'm not using Java 7.

Comment: You can simply use `"UTF-8"` (`String`) instead. It will lookup the charset and is guaranteed to never fail for the `UTF-8` charset.

Comment: `writeUTF` will work as long as the written number of bytes forms characters ignorable to the server. But writing a text of different length can make it break suddenly creating non-ignorable or even invalid `UTF-8` bytes.

Comment: @Holger, Can you elaborate more when you say "_writeUTF will work as long as the written number of bytes forms characters ignorable to the server._" Are you referring to the characters which are more than two bytes ?

Comment: Well, `writeUTF` writes the numbers of bytes as big endian 2 byte number before the characters. This number will be interpreted as characters by receivers not expecting such a number. If the number of bytes is below 32, the header consists of a `0` byte and a control character, both being ignored most probably. If the byte count is bigger than 32 you might see a spurious printable character before your string but if it is between 128 and 255 it will form a byte creating an invalid `UTF-8` sequence. Writing more than 256 bytes will create a combination of the former.