# Error 400 because of accents on a JSON field

Tags: java, json

I make a GET request on an URL and I retrieve some informations in the response. One of this information contains accents. I make after a PUT request with on the body these informations and others.

When I make this request I have a 400 error because of accents.

How can accept accents when I make the request?

**CODE**

GetInformation

```
ArrayList<String> infos = new ArrayList<>();


String urlGet = "URL";
URL obj = new URL(urlGet);
HttpURLConnection conGet = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

//add request header
conGet.setRequestMethod("GET");
conGet.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

String response = sendRequest("GET", conGet, urlGet, "");

JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject jobj2 = jobj.getJSONObject("Applications");
JSONArray jArr = jobj2.getJSONArray("Application");
JSONObject jobj3 = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
String name = jobj3.getString("Name");
String shortDescription = jobj3.getString("ShortDescriptionLocal");
String basicat = jobj3.getString("Basicat");

infos.add(name);
infos.add(shortDescription);
infos.add(basicat);
```

Put in an other request

```
String name = infos.get(0);
String shortDescription = infos.get(1);
String basicat = infos.get(2);

String urlPut = "URL";
URL obj = new URL(urlPut);
HttpURLConnection conPut = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

//add request header
conPut.setRequestMethod("PUT");
conPut.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

String urlParameters = "{\"name\": " + "\"" + name + "\"" + ",\"description\": " + "\"" + shortDescription.replace("\"",  "\\\"").replace("\n"," ")}";

String response = sendRequest("PUT", conPut, urlPut, urlParameters);
```

For information it's the shortDescription field that contains accents.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It's french : for example : à fédérer  avec

Comment: It send a request by specifying the method request and retrieve with a BufferedReader the response

Comment: It's a problem of accents because when I remove accents, there is no problem. The request is well executed

Comment: your question is too broad. no one can help you with your given informations. we need to see how you send the body to the server. there is no problem with your accents... there is a problem with how you create the outputstream and send the body to the server... for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266799/urlconnection-encoding-issue-with-accent-character

Comment: Thanks, your url help me :) you're right it's my OutputStream which had a problem :)